# UISearchBar Custom InputView Crash in iOS8

Tags: uitextfield, ios8, uisearchbar

I have `UISearchBar` that with Custom InputView. Now i can't set Custom InputView for UISearchBar in `iOS8`. It's crashing.

Here is how i set Custom InputView for UISearchBar

```
for(int i =0; i<[[[self.sBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] count]; i++) {
            if([[[[self.sBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                [[[(UITextField*)[sBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:i] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont" size:15]];
                UITextField* search=[[(UITextField*)[sBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0]subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
                search.delegate = self;

                [[[(UITextField*)[self.sBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:i] setInputView:MyKeyboard];
            }
```

Here is crash Log.

```
Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.company.MyApp"
2014-09-23 13:34:13.816 MyApp[1651:61729] Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.company.MyApp"
```

It's working fine in iOS 7 But Now Crash in iOS8.

How can i fix it?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem , can any body help me out on this.

Comment: @Shazad . I answered for my own questions that work for iOS8. Check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answers for my own question.

But you need to check iOS Version first for `iOS8` because this code doesn't work perfectly for `iOS7`.

```
    if([systemVersion isEqualToString:@"8"])
    {
        UITextField *search = (UITextField *)[[[self.sBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        [search setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:15]];
        [search setInputView:self.customKeyboard];
        [search setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.customKeyboard setTextView:search];

        [search reloadInputViews];
    }
```